# Python OpenID Library Usage

Tags: python, openid

Can anyone explain me steps using openid library which is mentioned here.
I have import all package of janrain openid in my programe but I cant understand actual flow of code.

The process should basically follow this plan:

Add an OpenID login field somewhere on your site. When an OpenID is entered in that field and the form is submitted, it should make a request to the your site which includes that OpenID URL.

First, the application should instantiate a Consumer with a session for per-user state and store for shared state. using the store of choice.

Next, the application should call the 'begin' method on the Consumer instance. This method takes the OpenID URL. The begin method returns an AuthRequest object.

Next, the application should call the redirectURL method on the AuthRequest object. The parameter return_to is the URL that the OpenID server will send the user back to after attempting to verify his or her identity. The realm parameter is the URL (or URL pattern) that identifies your web site to the user when he or she is authorizing it. Send a redirect to the resulting URL to the user's browser.

That's the first half of the authentication process. The second half of the process is done after the user's OpenID Provider sends the user's browser a redirect back to your site to complete their login.

When that happens, the user will contact your site at the URL given as the return_to URL to the redirectURL call made above. The request will have several query parameters added to the URL by the OpenID provider as the information necessary to finish the request.

Get an Consumer instance with the same session and store as before and call its complete method, passing in all the received query arguments.

There are multiple possible return types possible from that method. These indicate the whether or not the login was successful, and include any additional information appropriate for their type.

Comment: Hmm, the flow is pretty well described in your question already :) Which steps are confusing? What web framework are you using?

Comment: i am using python_openid2.4 library and want to make a openid plugins for my website which supports only userid and password this time. i have just want to use that library and import into my programe. how can i do that. can you be explain plzzzzzz

Answer (score 0):

[web.py](http://webpy.org) includes a [webopenid module](http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/api#web.webopenid) that implements a complete, if basic, OpenID authentication system using the Janrain.  Using the included `host` class, you can add OpenID-backed authentication to your project.  To actually *pull* interesting data from the OpenID provider, though, you'll need to add AX and SReg request/response handling.